# Reduction of affine points on elliptic curve over local field

Tags: elliptic-curves, local-field

In Silverman's AEC, Proposition VII.2.2, the author has a point $(x, y) \in E(K)$, where $K$ is a local field with uniformizer $\pi$ for the maximal ideal of its ring of integers $R$, and the author says, "Since $(x,y)$ reduces modulo $\pi$ to the point at infinity on $\tilde{E}(k)$, we see that $v(x) < 0$ and $v(y) < 0$."

I think this is a basic question but I fail to see why $v(x) < 0$ and $v(y) < 0$. In particular, if the points $(\pi, 1 / \pi)$ is on $E$, then $v(\pi) = 1 > 0$, but $(\pi, 1/\pi) = [\pi : 1 / \pi : 1] = [\pi^2 : 1 : \pi]$ in projective coordinates, and $[\pi^2 : 1 : \pi]$ reduces to $[0 : 1 : 0]$, the point at infinity on $\tilde{E}(k)$. So somewhere I have gone wrong, can anyone point out where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If either $x$ or $y$ has non-negative valuation, then the other one does, thanks to the normalized Weierstrass equation $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$. For example, your counterexample can't be a point on an elliptic curve with normalized Weierstrass equation since $y^2$ has negative valuation but the right hand side has non-negative valuation.

But then if both $x$ and $y$ have non-negative valuation, then the point $(x, y)$, which really denotes the point $[x: y: 1]$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, cannot possibly reduce to $[0: 1: 0]$.

Comment: (I haven't got Silverman in front of me but if I remember right he doesn't appeal to the theory of Néron models but insists on Weierstrass equations being normalized in the sense that the coefficients have non-negative valuation and the discriminant has as small a (non-negative) valuation as possible. He does this precisely to be able to make arguments like the one you are citing.)

Comment: Thanks so much! This connection between the valuations of the two variables from the requirement that the Weierstrass equation has coefficients in $R$ is exactly what I was missing.